# How can I implement cooperative lightweight threading with C on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, multithreading, macos

I'm trying to find a lightweight cooperative threading solution to try implementing an actor model.
As far as I know, the only solution is setcontext/getcontext,
but the functionality is deprecated(?) by Apple. I'm confused by why they did this; however, I'm finding replacement for this.

- Pthreads are not an option because I need cooperative model instead of preemptive model to control context switching timing precisely/manually without expensive locking.

-- edit --

Reason of avoiding pthreads:
Because pthreads are not cooperative/deterministic and too expensive. I need actor model for game logic code, so thousand of execution context are required at minimal. Hardware threading requires MB of memory and expense to create/destruct. And parallelism is not important. In fact, I just need concurrent execution of many functions. This can be implemented with many divided functions and some kind of object model, but my goal is reducing those overheads.

If I know something wrong, please correct me. It'll be very appreciated.

Comment: You are definitely making life difficult for yourself by ruling out Pthreads - they are the automatic obvious solution.  Why do you think that the Pthread scheduling will be a problem?

Comment: @Janathan I added the reason :)

Comment: OK. I agree that pthreads are not cooperative. But they are the closest to the metal threading model so they are actually the cheapest (the problem with that is the responsibility is now on the developer to add the expensive part (cooperation)).

Comment: @Martin Well... In fact, my main goal is also reducing programmer's work. Game logic execution over multiple ticks requires heavy extra structural work can be effectively eliminated with cooperative threading. I expect cooperative threading will greatly reduce many of my work if I implement it once.

Comment: @Enoil: Yes I am sure cooperative will reduce your work but somebody else has to build the cooperative stuff ontop of the basic threads.

Comment: To get a message to someone via comments, you have to get at least the first three letters of the name you quote in '@Xyz' to match their actual handle.  I didn't see your update because you misspelled my name.  Not that it makes much difference this time, but just an FYI.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh I'm sorry and thanks. I'll take care!

Comment: @Martin I reviewed Pthreads, and realized it's useful for generic applications event many thread count. And any other approaches based on stack has similar overheads with pthreads in memory usage. But I can't sure it's performance because I couldn't find any document about Pthreads in user mode. Can you recommend any document about performance of Pthreads?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious 'lightweight' solution is to avoid complex nested calling except for limited situations where the execution time will be tightly bounded, then store an explicit state structure for each "thread" and implement the main program logic as a state machine that's easily suspendable/resumable at most points. Then you can simply swap out the pointer to the state structure for 'context switch'. Basically this technique amounts to keeping all of your important state variables, including what would conventionally be local variables, in the state structure.

Whether this is worthwhile probably depends on your reason for avoiding pthreads. If your reason is to be portable to non-POSIX systems, or if you really need deterministic program flow, then it may be worthwhile. But if you're just worried about performance overhead and memory synchronization issues, I think you should use pthreads and manage these issues. If you avoid unnecessary locking, use fine-grained locks, and minimize the amount of time locks are held, performance should not suffer.

**Edit:** Based on your further details posted in the comments on the main question, I think the solution I've proposed is the right one. Each actor should have their own context in which you store the state of the actor's action/thinking/etc. You would have a `run_actor` function which would take an actor context and a number of "ticks" to advance the actor's state by, and a `run_all_actors` function which would iterate over a list of active actors and call `run_actor` for each with the specified number of ticks.

Further, note that this solution still allows you to use real threads to take advantage of SMP/multicore machines. You simply divide the actors up between threads. You may need some degree of locking if one actor needs to examine another's context (e.g. for collision detection).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I can agree state machine approach in general. However, this is a trial of simplifying execution over multiple ticks. And discussion about design of game engine is not range of this question :)

Answer (score 1):

I was researching this question as well, and I ran across GNU Pth (not to be confused with Pthreads). See http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/

It aims to be a portable solution for cooperative threads.  It does mention it is implemented via setcontext/getcontext if available (so it may not be on Mac OSX).  Otherwise it says it uses longjmp/setjmp, but it's not clear to me how that works.

Hope this is helpful to anyone who searches for this question.

Comment: I built `pth` with *Homebrew*. But I couldn't test it well because Xcode hangs at `SIGUSR1` and doesn't continues. Anyway without Xcode, it looks working. If I find some workaround that enables debugging code with `pth`, I'll update this :)

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the some of required functionalities from `setcontext/getcontext` are implemented in [`libunwind`](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/).

Unfortunately the library won't be compiled on Mac OS X because of deprecation of the `setcontext/getcontext`. Anyway Apple has implemented their own `libunwind` which is compatible with GNU's implementation at source level. The library is exist on Mac OS X 10.6, 10.7, and iOS. (I don't know exact version in case of iOS)

This library is not documented, but I could find the headers from these locations.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/include/libunwind.h
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/include/libunwind.h
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/usr/include/libunwind.h
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/libunwind.h
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/libunwind.h
```

There was a note  in the header file that to go GNU `libunwind` site for documentation.

I'll bet on the library.